# C++ weird expressions are compiled just fine

Tags: c++

Why are the following valid C++ expressions? These aren't lambdas

```
[]{}();
{}[]{};
```

Can someone explain them to me?

Comment: Yes these are lambdas.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The first is a lambda with no parameter list and a subsequent call.
`[]{}` is equivalent to `[](){}` so the whole line is equivalent to

```
[](){}();
```

---

The second is a pair of braces, which introduce and then immediately close a scope, followed by an unused lambda definition with no parameter list:

```
{
  // empty scope
}
[]{}; // lambda
```

---

You can refer to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda for the variations on lambda definition syntax.

Answer (score 41):

- This one is a lambda call

  ```
  []{}();
  ```

  it is equivalent to

  ```
  [](){}();
  ```
- The second is an empty scope, followed by a (unused) lambda.

Parens are optional for lambda without parameter.